# Test custom Jackson Serializer is not working

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

I have a Custom Serializer that serialize the LocalDateTime for me.

```
    public class LocalDateTimeJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

        private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;

        @Override
        public void serialize(LocalDateTime date, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            final String dateString = date.format(FORMATTER);
            generator.writeString(dateString);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that my test is not working, it is like my jsonGenerator still be null after the serialization

```
  @Test
        public void serialises_LocalDateTime() throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
            Writer jsonWriter = new StringWriter();
            JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(jsonWriter);
            SerializerProvider serializerProvider = new ObjectMapper().getSerializerProvider();
            LocalDateTimeJsonSerializer  ldt = new LocalDateTimeJsonSerializer();
            ldt.serialize(LocalDateTime.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0), jsonGenerator, serializerProvider);
            jsonGenerator.flush();
            //assertEquals(jsonWriter.toString(), "2000-01-01T00:00:00");
        }
```

.. any Idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by *jsonGenerator still be null after the serialization*?
When I uncomment your `assertEquals` and run the test I get:
`org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<["2000-01-01T00:00:00"]> but was:<[2000-01-01T00:00:00]>`, which is quite a different behavior.

Comment: Yes .. very weird .. it is working ...